# html5 validation issue on input hidden

Tags: javascript, html, required

I am facing issue validation issue. I have 100+ input fields on my form. Some fields are showing and some are hidden.
Can we skip validation on input fields which are hidden?

```
<input name="class_range" required>
```

I am hiding fields with CSS. I don't want to write 100+ statements.

Comment: Do you hide them with `display: none` or how?

Comment: i mean make the ones that are hidden not required, or keep track of those that are hidden and in your validation code *dont* validate or process the hidden ones

Comment: Just a friendly suggestion: 100+ input fields in a form doesn't sound like great UI design. Maybe break it up into several forms/pages?

Comment: The question is how you are hiding the inputs.  Are you doing it with css or are the inputs `type="hidden"`?  Because ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required ) "The attribute is not supported or relevant to range and color, as both have default values. **It is also not supported on hidden as it can not be expected that a user to fill out a form that is hidden.** Nor is it supported on any of the button types, including image."

Comment: Actually, there are many ways of hiding them with css using width, opacity, display... And if I'm not wrong some of them apply the required attribute and others don't but is difficult to guess which code is he using

Comment: @peprm please tell

Comment: We should know first how you hide them so that we can try to reproduce the bug and try other ways. My guess is that with display: none that field should not be validated, that's why I were asking